# Creating animated Splash Screen in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, splash-screen

I would like to create an animated splash screen using WPF. All the tutorials I have come across actually renders text in animation.. For example, "loading module" etc. But I would like to animate the images inside the wpf splash screen code.

I have a png which acts like a background, and then I need to show some kind of animation with that. Do I need to use a .gif file or I can do it in WPF with DispatcherTimer and Storyboard.

Comment: You can do that via standard WPF animation capabilities (Storyboard). What have you tried?

Comment: A pretty good simple example on WPF animation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial

Comment: Basically, I  would like to create something like this http://www.animateit.net/categories.php?cat_id=218&page=11  -  
Frog Gets Spider Animated Gif ... I have a frog image, a tongue image and a bug image separate, but not able to put it in animation...